# Has anyone tried to get multi node H20 working inside of Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, h2o

Based on this [document](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-lambert/5/docs-website/deployment/multinode.html) it seems like I could just run the H20 jar file in several pods with K8s services in front of them. I can then reference the K8s services in the IP address file. Has anyone tried anything like that before?

Answer (score 0):

This repo might be helpful for you. https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-kubeflow. 
Basically, for k8s, create a docker image, make a deployment on k8s with proper specifications. If you use the steps in the above repo, make sure to have the proper RBAC authorizations.